Redirect Console.Write() Output to new allocated Console in C# - WPF
I have a little project with 3 buttons:

open console
write to console
close console

For opening and closing I use this:
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern bool AllocConsole();

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern bool FreeConsole();

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern int AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);

I can do Console.ReadLine() to get user input, but I cannot output to that console.
I am pretty sure, that this question was probably already answered, but I cannot find an answer yet.
I tried different suggestions from GPT, but those did not work.

Did you see No console output when using AllocConsole and target architecture x86??  It's an older question but this answer and this one also seem up to date, so do give them a look.
